# How readdir function is working inside while loop in C?

Tags: c, while-loop, readdir

I'm learning C and this piece of code is a part from tree command implementation in C. And I don't understand how `readdir` function is working inside the `while` loop.

```
static struct t_node *create_tree(char *root_name) {
    DIR *dir = opendir(root_name);
    struct dirent *dr = { NULL };
    struct t_node *ptr_tstart = NULL, *temp = NULL, *temp1 = NULL;
    char *name=(char *)calloc(2000, sizeof(char));

    if (dir == NULL) {
        printf("\nFailed to open ..!!");
        printf(" : %s", root_name);
        return NULL;
    }

    while ((dr = readdir(dir)) != NULL) {
        printf("\ndr->d_name = %s", dr->d_name);

        if (strcmp((dr->d_name), ".") != 0 && strcmp((dr->d_name), "..") != 0) {
            temp = create_tnode(dr->d_name);
        } else {
            temp = NULL;
            continue;
        }

        printf("\ntemp1!=NULL => %d", temp1 != NULL);
        ...
    }
}
```

The current directory is **cprogs**, and inside **cprogs** there are 2 other directories **hello** and **tree**. When the `create_tree` struct is called, the `root_name` is `"/root/cprogs"`. After that it goes to the `while` loop and what I see in the logs is this:

```
dr->d_name = .
dr->d_name = ..
dr->d_name = hello

temp1!=NULL => 0
```

And I don't understand why `d_name` is `"."`, then `".."` and after that is `"hello"`. So first time the value for `d_name` is `"."`, after that it goes to the `if` statement and it isn't `true`, so it goes to `else` statement, and when hit `continue` it goes to the `while` loop. Why the `d_name` becomes `".."` at this moment? And after that why it becomes "hello"? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74890409/what-happens-in-c-function-readdir-from-dirent-h), and thanks to great answers there I can answer yours.

It's this line

```
>   56   dirp->offset += dp->d_reclen;
```

[here](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/readdir.c;h=c9a04dc16081906da6b48ae49d20860bffb5e916;hb=HEAD#l26) in the glibc's source.

Every time you call that function to check if it returns 0 or not, it moves down an entry in the file list by a system call to the kernel ( getdents ) and returns a new [structure dirstream](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/dirstream.h;h=a0d8acf08dc0066fc2ef6a1d759c480a05904438;hb=HEAD) defined as DIR.

In the end it returns 0 and the "while" cycle exits.

Answer (score 0):

It's . and then .. because inside a directory, there are links for the current directory and the parent directory, namely *.* and *..* ,
The strcmp check is there because you don't want to list your directory infinite times (going to . and then to . again etc) and if it is, ignore it and continue.